# choosing between two files while making a git pull

Tags: git, git-fork

I use git with Fork tool
I have a branch "branch1" rebased on master

```
branch 1
  |
  | commit1
  | 
  | commit2
  |
  | commit3
  |
  | master
  |
```

and its origin : I don't know why, there are multiple commit markers (dots) on graphical interface of Fork corresponding to other branchs

```
origin/branch1
  |
  | branch2
  |
  | branch3
  |
  | branch4
  |
etc....
```

Now, I checkout to local branch1 and try to pull, but Fork propose to merge some files by choosing between 2 files, not merging them by adding parts of code from 2 files, but choosing between 2 whole version.

And the issue I have is choosing either a version1 or version2 of the file. But I don't know which version to choose. What strategy must I adopt and how can I resolve it ?

### UPDATE

I add that I have to choose between two version from two other developers

Comment: Has the file changed the EOL format on either of the 2 branches? That might explain why it's making you decide between 2 whole versions of the file.

Comment: thank you for your answer eftshift0, may be I don't know. Do you think I take a huge risk choosing one version instead of the other

Comment: Well.... you would not be merging correctly. It's not too difficult to find out on git bash. Run `git show one-branch:file-path | file -`. Replace `one-branch` for each branch and compare the output. If one talks about CRLF and other doesn't then EOL format got messed up.

Comment: Another way is to diff the file between the 2 branches _with_ and _without_ using `-w` option. If you get full file removal without `-w` and only a bunch of lines with `-w`, the EOL format got busted on one of the branches.

Comment: Thanks eftshift0. If the EOL format get messed up in one of version, then you have to choose the other version regardless a bunch of line that may differ ? How to conciliate both. Furthermore when you say "you get full file removal" did you mean that it shows all the lines as difference ?

Comment: Yes... all lines removed, all lines added. And the technique to get it done cortectly would be to rewrite the history of the branch where it was messed up so that the change _does not_ happen at all. Alternatively you might create a new revision on top of that branch to change back to the original EOL format. Then merge should be a _normal_ one.